# Issue with function to check if tree is a BST

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree, nodes

So I have a function to check if a tree is a bst(if every node only has smaller values on its left and larger values on its right). Every other function works and the problem is with this one (second one just calls helper). I think the issue has something to do with the recursive call root-left hitting null but I am not sure and even if it is not sure how to fix. Can add more code as needed. Any help is appreciated.

visual studio error i get is : R00t -> left was nullptr
other compiler: segmentation fault core dumped.

```
bool isBSThelper(TreeNode* R00t) 
{



        if (R00t == NULL)
            return true;
        //if (R00t->left != NULL && (R00t->info < R00t->left->info))
        if (R00t->info < R00t->left->info)
            return false;
        //if (R00t->right != NULL && (R00t->info < R00t->right->info))
        if (R00t->info > R00t->right->info)
            return false;

        return isBSThelper(R00t->left) && isBSThelper(R00t->right);



}

bool TreeType::isBST() const
{
    return isBSThelper(root);
}
```

Comment: Why on earth would you call a variable `R00t`? Why are the null pointer checks commented out?

Comment: make sure R00t->left not NULL, R00t->right not NULL

Comment: I will try that kaitan. And those checks didn't work last time I tried so I commented them out bessie

Comment: even with if (R00t->left != NULL || R00t->right != NULL) error persists

Comment: Your original check didn't work because there's a typo in `(R00t->info < R00t->right->info)`. The comparison is the wrong way around. Your new check is wrong because if one of the sides is nullptr and the other isn't you'll still dereference a null pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment

```
even with if (R00t->left != NULL || R00t->right != NULL) error persists
```

the problem would persist. Let me rewrite and iterate from there (since I can't comment to ask for clarification -new user). If your code was like

```
bool isBSThelper(TreeNode* R00t) {
    if ( R00t == NULL )
        return true;
    if ( R00t->left != NULL || R00t->right != NULL ) {
        if ( R00t->info < R00t->left->info )
            return false;
        if ( R00t->info < R00t->right->info )
            return false;
    }

    return isBSThelper(R00t->left) && isBSThelper(R00t->right);
}
```

then you would potentially still encounter the same problem, since the expression

```
if (R00t->left != NULL || R00t->right != NULL) {
```

would still make this expression with values

```
R00t->left != NULL
```

but

```
R00t->right == NULL
```

evaluate to true.

One solution might be

1. To make sure R00T->left and R00t->right are either valid (pointing to a node) or NULL (preferably nullptr if you are using C++)
2. And code like this:

```
bool isBSThelper( TreeNode* R00t ) {
    if ( R00t == NULL )
        return true;
    if ( R00t->left != NULL && R00t->info > R00t->left->info )
        return false;
    if ( R00t->right!= NULL && R00t->info > R00t->right->info )
        return false;

    return isBSThelper( R00t->left ) && isBSThelper( R00t->right );
}
```

And the problem would be no more. (1) is critical.

An additional note: Your code does not check

```
if (R00t->left != NULL && R00t->right!= NULL && R00t->left->info < R00t->right->info)
        return false;
```

which is another property of a Binary Search Tree (or obviously using ">" instead of "<" here as you see fit).